# Npm install only includes old MongoDB versions...?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am building an app for a client database but realized you can't use case-insensitive queries with my current version of MongoDB.. I went to install the new version using:

```
npm install mongodb
```

but my version is still 2.3.0 or something.

I know I could just create a lowercaseName within the client model but I would rather not use duplicate data.

Does anyone know if I am doing something wrong with npm install, or do I need to update manually?

Comment: That's a driver not the database.

Comment: Weird, I still can't use case insensitive searches.. do I need to change the firstName within my client model to something other than string?

Comment: As Darkrum said, you installed the Mongo Node.js driver, not a new version of MongoDB. If you want to update the database, here is some help: https://docs.opsmanager.mongodb.com/current/tutorial/change-mongodb-version/

Comment: Or perhaps the general community edition installs would be more useful: [Install MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/installation/). Point is that case insensitive search features are only introduced in MongoDB "server" 3.4. Newer "drivers" have the access methods, but you actually need a "server" version that supports them. Note also that whilst you may not "duplicate data", there is a performance cost for doing this in the way the index information is stored. It also cannot be "undone". So consider carefully.